# Upgrading RestKit from 0.10 to 0.20 problems

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

**I can't figure out how to correct the errors I'm getting after having upgraded from RestKit 0.10 to 0.20... Can anyone help?**

Thanks!

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

// Wain, I added this RKResponseDescriptor
            RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor
              responseDescriptorWithMapping:[Feed mapping] method:RKRequestMethodAny 
              pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"springs" statusCodes:nil];


            // These 4 lines has errors and needs to be fixed
        // No visible @interface for 'RKObjectManager' declares the selector 'loader'
            [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] 
            loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/springs/?apikey=xxx" 
            usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
              loader.onDidLoadObjects = ^(NSArray *objects){

            springs = objects;

        // These 2 lines have errors that need to be fixed
        // Use of undeclared identifier 'loader'
           [loader.mappingProvider  setMapping:[Spring mapping] forKeyPath:@"springs"];
           loader.onDidLoadResponse = ^(RKResponse *response){
}
```

*I see the GitHub help page for this, but I can't figure this out with just that on my own.  Really appreciate it!*

***Update***

Ok I think I understand how to replace the first line, just by using
 `[RKObjectManager.sharedManager getObjectsAtPath:@"/springs/?apikey=xxx" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)`...

**But I'm still not sure what to do with the `loader.onDidLoadObjects = ^(NSArray *objects)` part!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 0.1x code you show downloads the response data and then calls your callback to ask what to do with it, so you supply the mapping in the callback.

0.2x doesn't work like that. It takes all of the mappings as configuration before you make the request, and the mappings are associated with response descriptors (so RestKit can search all the config options and apply everything that matches).

So, you need to take your configuration and apply it to the `RKObjectManager` before you actually 'get' any content from the server.

Comment: How do you apply it to the `RKObjectManager` before you 'get' content from the server?  Is my updated code correct, and your referring to only the part I hadn't updated yet (`loader.onDidLoadObjects`)?  I appreciate the broad context of your answer, just trying to drill down to a specific solution.  Thanks!

Comment: Create an `RKResponseDescriptor` instance, using `[Spring mapping` and add it to the object manager, just after you create the object manager.

Comment: I updated the code with the `RKResponseDescriptor`... did I do that part right?

Comment: You don't appear to have added it to the object manager. Other than that it could be ok.