# RestKit RKObjectMapping error, update from 0.10 to 0.20

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm updating RestKit from 0.10 to 0.20 and getting some errors I'm trying to figure out.

**I'm getting errors on the Spring.m file for the `MappingForClass:usingBlock`, no @interface for `mapKeyPathsToAttributes`, and no @interface for `hasMany:withMapping`.**

Can't seem to figure this out myself.

Spring.h

```
@interface Spring : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *id;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *leafs;

+ (RKObjectMapping *)mapping;

@end
```

Spring.m

```
@implementation Spring

// Creating RestKit object mapping variable, THIS IS WHERE ERRORS OCCUR
+ (RKObjectMapping *)mapping {
    RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[self class] usingBlock:^(RKObjectMapping *mapping) {
       [mapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:
            @"name", @"name",
            @"id", @"id",
            nil];
        [mapping hasMany:@"leafs" withMapping:[Leaf mapping]];
    }];

    return objectMapping;
}

@end
```

*I'm using https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Upgrading-from-v0.10.x-to-v0.20.0 to help me try to figure this out.*

Comment: What did you try to replace the attribute and relationship mappings?

Comment: Sorry not sure if I understand your question?  Above is my original code, and I haven't tried to update anything yet because I'm trying to figure out how to.  Thanks Wain!

Comment: This is the closest the guide gets: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Upgrading-from-v0.10.x-to-v0.20.0#serialization so you may be better just looking at the main object mapping page...

Comment: I'm looking at the other question that I'm working on in tandem with this, and your answer to it, and wondering if the `RKRequestDescriptor` should go here in my Model, or in my ViewController `viewDidLoad`?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739221/upgrading-restkit-from-0-10-to-0-20-problems/22741964?noredirect=1#comment34729671_22741964

Comment: I usually have a data controller as you only want to setup this configuration once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: Needed to use `RKRequestDescriptor`